# How to Filter List Box on Report in MS Access that is Based on a Text Box Value?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a report in Access that I am needing some assistance with.

There is a text box field in my report named Company Name. I need the value of this text box to filter the list box that I have set-up in my Access Report.

Right now, the list box is showing every record, regardless of whether or not it is associated with the text box value.

I've tried a number of different ideas, but can't get any of them to work. RIght now, I am doing something like:

```
Private Sub CompanyName_Change()
    Me.List1.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Listbox is seldom practical for a report. Consider a subreport. Are you viewing report in ReportView? Why would textbox Change event be triggered on a report?

Comment: I don't even see Change event on PropertySheet for textbox on report.